# How to view test results in Hudson?

Tags: hudson, test

I cannot find a link to test results in hudson. How do I view test results (i.e. which of the tests failed) in Hudson web interface?

I have "Publish JUnit test result report" checked for the project. I'm pretty sure that "Test report XMLs" has the correct setting: (`trunk/tmp/selenium-test-run/*.xml`). I used workspace explorer to see whether Hudson does see the test results directory (it does). And there is a test results files in this directory.

But I still cannot find a link to results viewer. Does Hudson has this feature at all?

P.S.: I did search through online docs, found nothing. I did google it. Found nothing useful. I did not read the whole documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you trying to publish JUnit test results or selenium test results? If it is the latter, try the [Seleniumhq Plugin](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org//display/HUDSON/Seleniumhq+Plugin). Since I never used it, you have to find the right configuration by yourself but there are a few questions about this topic on StackOverflow. Just as an info there is a second selenium plugin available, but I think the I mentioned is the right one for displaying the test results.

Comment: These are actually phpUnit tests. I figured out that XML results files are not exactly the same as jUnit produces. xUnit plugin resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I've had trouble with getting the path's to these before.  This one works for, In hudson I have defined a job called "hello", the path in hudson is set to:

```
hello/junit-results/TEST-hello.TestHello.xml
```

Which on the filesystem is at:

```
/home/me/.hudson/jobs/hello/workspace/hello/junit-results
```

I've some vague idea that the "performance" plugin plays a role in the publishing of junit results but maybe that's just for the graphs.

http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Performance+Plugin